# Javascript: Insert an Emoticon text to a textfield onclick of a list/display of Emoticon Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can someone please help. This is my script that collects a list of emoticons and renders the alt keyword as a corresponding smiley that is drawn on the emoticon text area bar and thereafter renders the display on the preview div when the user hits enter.
But on clicking the smiley picture it pops up the the iterated list of pictures/images and when you select any one of them it renders the drawing on the textfield but on clicking it the second time it fails to render and just gives the text that is the alt text of the image.
Also, when you hit on send the drawn style refuses to be displayed on the div preview.

```
<div class="chat">
    <div class="preview"></div><br>
      <textarea name="comment" rows="2" tabindex="4" id="comment" placeholder="Type here..."></textarea>
  </div>
```

Below is a list of my script on what I have done so far.

```
<html>
<head><title>Welcome to select emoticons</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c0d3.googlecode.com/files/jquery-latest.pack.js'></script>
<script src="https://jquery-elastic.googlecode.com/svn-history/r30/trunk/jquery.elastic.source.js"></script>
<script>
var smileys = {
    ':)': '<img src="images/smileys/happy.png" border="0" alt="" />',
    ':-)': '<img src="images/smileys/sad.png" border="0" alt="" />',
    ':D': '<img src="images/smileys/Cool.png" border="0" alt="" />',
};

function smilyMe(msg) {
    msg = msg.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
    for (var key in smileys) {
        msg = msg.replace(key, smileys[key]);
    }
    return msg;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".chat > textarea").bind("keyup", function(e) {
    $(".chat > div").html(smilyMe($(".chat > textarea").val()));
  });
  $('#maintbox').on('keyup',function() {
    $(this).css('height','auto');
    $(this).css('height',Math.max(this.scrollHeight)+'px');
  });
  $('#showhide_emobox').click(function(){
    $('#emobox').fadeToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
  $(".embtn").click(function(event){
    var prevMsg = $(".chat > textarea").val();
    var emotiText = $(event.target).attr("alt");
    $(".chat > textarea").html(prevMsg + emotiText);
     $(".chat > div").html(smilyMe($(".chat > textarea").val()));
  });
    $('textarea').elastic();
});
</script>
<style>
#maintbox {
    position:relative;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    min-height: 50px;
    width: 450;
    top:100px;
}
div.chat {
    width: 100%;
}
.preview {
    max-width: 400px;
    font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000000;
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0; z-index:997;
}
div.chat > textarea {
    font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif;
    font-size:14px;
    margin-left:-2px;
    margin-top:-2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    min-height: 50px;
    width: 510px;
    resize:none;
    float:left;
    position:absolute; color:transparent;
    top:0; left:0; z-index:998; background: transparent;
}
.em {
    position:relative;
    margin:1px 2px;
    float:right;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
.em img {
    margin-top:1px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:white;
    display:block;
    transition:all 1s ease;
}
#emobox {
    background:#fff;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    bottom:25px;
    left:-176px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#emobox img {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:5px 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="maintbox">
  <div class="chat">
    <div class="preview"></div><br>
      <textarea name="comment" rows="2" tabindex="4" id="comment" placeholder="Type here..."></textarea>
  </div>
 </div>    
<div align="right">
<img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fez/512/FEZ-05-128.png" width="25" alt="" id="uploadMedia" style="padding:2px;cursor:pointer;" />
  <div class="em">
    <img src="http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/big-smile-256x256.png" width="25" id="showhide_emobox"/>
      <div id="emobox">
        <img src="images/smileys/happy.png" alt=":)" class="embtn" />
        <img src="images/smileys/sad.png" alt=":-)" class="embtn" />
        <img src="images/smileys/Cool.png" alt=":D" class="embtn" />
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please assist!

Link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/872zb7gc

Comment: Is like my question is kind of difficult!

Comment: Please, you can add a jsfiddle. If you don't like jsfiddle there's tons of tools for this purpose, like codepen. With a fiddle I can help you better :) Have a nice day!

Comment: I made a fiddle and I update your post. It works, but have a weird behaviour. What do you need exactly?

Comment: Hi Marcos, I want a situation when I click on 1 irrespective of the number of times let it retain 1 on the textarea instead of giving the alt text on second click and on hitting enter or send let it append it to a preview div. Regards.